# Formatting large integers in Python

Tags: python, string-formatting, largenumber

I am dealing with large integral numbers in my script and I want to format the numbers into strings using the `'K'`, `'M'` and `'B'` postfix chars to denote scale of thousands, millions or billionsб respectively.

Rather than rolling my own function, I wonder if there is an built-in function that either does this "out of the box", or at least would be useful when writing my own function to do this type of formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this in the Python standard library, but there's a nice example of what you want to achieve [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576385-format-a-number-for-human-consumption/).